# Deal with the result of postJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to implement something with jQuery and Vue.js:

[image]

And here is my script part:

```
<script>
function initVM(result) {
    // alert(result.num)
    var vm2 = new Vue({
        el: '#vm2',
        data: {
            // ③bind one item of the result as example
            rrr: result.num
        }
    });
    $('#vm2').show();
}


$(function() {
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#vm',
    data: {
        content: ''
    },

    methods: {
        submit: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var
                $form = $('#vm'),
                content = this.content.trim();

            // ①post textarea content to backend
            $form.postJSON('/api/parse', {
                content: content
            }, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    $form.showFormError(err);

                }
                else {
                    // ②receive a result dictionary
                    $('#vm').hide();
                    initVM(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Here is my html part:

```
<html>
<form id="vm", v-on="submit: submit">
    <textarea v-model="content" name="content"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Have a try!</button>
</form>
<div id="vm2" style="diplay:none;">
    <!-- ④show the result-->
    The result:
    {{ rrr }}
</div>
</html>
```

Here is the definition of `postJSON`

```
<script>
// ...
    postJSON: function (url, data, callback) {
        if (arguments.length===2) {
            callback = data;
            data = {};
        }
        return this.each(function () {
            var $form = $(this);
            $form.showFormError();
            $form.showFormLoading(true);
            _httpJSON('POST', url, data, function (err, r) {
                if (err) {
                    $form.showFormError(err);
                    $form.showFormLoading(false);
                }
                callback && callback(err, r);
            });
        });
// ...
// _httpJSON
function _httpJSON(method, url, data, callback) {
var opt = {
    type: method,
    dataType: 'json'
};
if (method==='GET') {
    opt.url = url + '?' + data;
}
if (method==='POST') {
    opt.url = url;
    opt.data = JSON.stringify(data || {});
    opt.contentType = 'application/json';
}
$.ajax(opt).done(function (r) {
    if (r && r.error) {
        return callback(r);
    }
    return callback(null, r);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    return callback({'error': 'http_bad_response', 'data': '' + jqXHR.status, 'message': 'something wrong! (HTTP ' + jqXHR.status + ')'});
});
}
</script>
```

The process can be described as:

1. Post the content to backend
2. Receive the result and hide the form
3. Create a new Vue with the result
4. Show the result in a div which is binding with the new Vue instance

Actually, I do receive the result successfully, which is proved by the `alert(result.num)` statement, but nothing find in `vm2`'s div except `The result:`

Where is the problem? Or please be free to teach me a simpler approach if there is, because I don't think what I am using is a good one.

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, my apologize! What do you mean I didn't use the `vm2`? How to use it? Sorry to ask this naive question.

Comment: You define the `vm2` variable but never actually use it anywhere, but you're right, it should not make a difference.

Comment: @Tomalak So when you want to implement this kind of process, what is a good practice?

Comment: Where does `postJSON()` come from? That's not a standard function...

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for your patient reply! I'm not quite sure but it extends `jQuery.form`. I'd show it in question part for you.

Comment: Looks a little obscure to me. I think you can remove that extension and work with `$.ajax({type: 'POST', ... })` - fewer modifications are better. But I can't say why the viewmodel does not render, at least not from looking at the code. Maybe you can try to reproduce the problem on jsFiddle (use their Ajax responders to simulate the Ajax requests).

Comment: @Tomalak Never mind, I'd try it! Thanks very much, especially for these two test sites you provide with, that helps a lot !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115163/discussion-between-spike-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's questioner.

Finally I found where is the problem.

The problem lays in **Mustache**: `{{ }}`

I use **jinja2**, a template engine for Python and **Vue.js**, a MVVM frontend framework. Both of them use `{{ }}` as delimiters.

So if anyone got trapped in the same situation with me, which I don't think there will be, please:

```
app.jinja_env.variable_start_string = '{{ '
app.jinja_env.variable_end_string = ' }}'  # change jinjia2 config
```

OR

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}'] # change vue config
```

Comment: Nice work finding the culprit and sharing the solution. Thanks!